# How to enter null password for WiFi?

Tags: backtrack-linux, wep, aircrack-ng

Well I've recovered a WEP Wi-Fi password using Aircrack-ng, and it says the password is 00:00:00:00:00 in hex, which is five times null. Backtrack represents the password in ASCII as dots, but I've tried that and it naturally didn't work. How do I enter that? I'm running Win8.1 / Backtrack. I've googled that null on Win is alt + 255, but that didn't work for me.

Any ideas are nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've managed to do it. I've typed alt + 255 in CMD (which seems to be null code), and then I right clicked on the cmd window, copied everything, pasted in notepad++, and selected just the chars I wanted.

Comment: Type `alt+255` in notepad directly and copy-paste. One step lesser :)